# CSS: How to control the maximum grow ratio in a gallery of different size images using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, photo-gallery

Given a set of different images with different ratios but all having a side (either height or width) of 400px, I wish I could control how much elements per row could be seen, or, said differently, control the moment when the browser would rather shrink elements, rather than keeping growing them.

Constraints:

1. The image shown are totally random images, not knowing in advance their size/ratio.
2. There should be no visible space between images.
3. Solution should preferably be in **CSS** and **portable**.
4. The images must be displayed in order, from left to right, columns (`column-count: x`) don't make this possible (AFAIK).

My markup is the following:

```css
#images {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  display: flex;
}

#images a {
  flex: auto;
}

#images img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>Gallery of different sized images</h1>
  <section id="images">
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/315" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/156" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/305" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/331/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/291/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/244" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/295/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/203" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/255/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/304/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/321" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/375/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/249/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/272/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/199" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/211" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/295/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/329" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/287" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/237" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/214/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/263/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/373" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/388/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/312" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/282/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/300" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/180/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/165/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/350" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/380/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/301" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/281/400" alt="kitty"></a>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Rendering is currently great for small width: ~300px width window:

[image: Rendering with about 300px width window]

When the size is bigger, e.g. ~800px width, the first image is enlarged a lot, almost 2x:

[image: Rendering with about 800px width window]

The browser only starts putting 2 elements on a same row when reaching ~840px width:

[image: Rendering with about 840px width window]

I wish to trigger this flex-rearrangement sooner so that images gets enlarged as less as possible (I even wish I could use `flex: 0 1 auto` to only allow shrinking and no growing).

The only solution I found so far, but looks hacky and do not work on *Firefox*, is to change the zoom factor, setting for example: `zoom: 0.7` on `#images`. This gives a desired result:

[[image: Rendering with about 800px width window], with zoom on 0.7[4]]

Any clean and portable CSS solution that exists?

Comment: Have you tried Media queries ? this is the perfect, set a max width on the mages and change it on different screen sizes

Comment: @ZohirSalak: Yes, tried the `zoom` property inside media queries, works, but not for Firefox I'm looking for a compatible solution. Setting max-width: that doesn't work wel, it will not be a flexible layout anymore, but a column-like, where every pictures have the same size, result is not nice, see: https://jsfiddle.net/f4wtxcs8/

Answer (score 0):

I found a *CSS*, portable way of doing it by simulating `zoom` with properties `width`, `height` and `transform: scale()`.

*Works*, but still looks like a *hacky* solution, it comes down to do something like:

```
#images {
  /* Simulating 2x zoom */
  width: 200% !important;
  height: 200% !important;
  transform: scale(0.5); /* 0.5 = 100 / 200 */
}
```

Full, working, solution in the snippet (look at the `@media` queries) below.

**Criticisms welcome!**

```css
#images {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  display: flex;
  /******** Start of solution: common part for #images container ********/
  /*
    In media queries, we use "transform: scale" for simulating zoom,
    in all cases it must be done from origin "0 0"
  */
  transform-origin: 0 0;

  /*
    The zoom simulation generates blank content: the original size is kept.
    Using float + negative margin will remove those 'margins'
  */
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -9999999px;
  margin-right: -9999999px;
  /******** End of solution: common part for #images container ********/
}

#images a {
  flex: auto;
}

#images img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/******** Start of solution: @media parts for #images container ********/
@media screen and (min-width: 200px) {
  #images {
    /* Simulating 2x zoom */
    width: 200% !important;
    height: 200% !important;
    transform: scale(0.5); /* 0.5 = 100 / 200 */
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  #images {
    width: 175% !important;
    height: 175% !important;
    transform: scale(0.571429); /* 0.571429 = 100 / 175 */
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  #images {
    width: 150% !important;
    height: 150% !important;
    transform: scale(0.6666667); /* 0.6666667 = 100 / 175 */
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  #images {
    width: 125% !important;
    height: 125% !important;
    transform: scale(0.8); /* 0.8 = 100 / 125 */
  }
}
/******** End of solution: @media parts for #images container ********/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>Gallery of different sized images</h1>
  <section id="images">
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/315" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/156" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/305" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/331/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/291/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/244" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/295/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/203" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/255/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/304/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/321" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/375/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/249/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/272/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/199" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/211" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/295/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/329" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/287" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/237" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/214/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/263/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/373" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/388/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/312" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/282/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/300" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/180/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/165/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/350" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/380/400" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/301" alt="kitty"></a>
    <a href="https://placekitten.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/281/400" alt="kitty"></a>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```